# How to handle large scene/game in unity3d?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a very very Big/Huge scene to load and I can't load it at once.

The one strategy i know is that  I divide the scene into multiple scenes and load my scenes it into async manner as my character controller move. I am moving my character controller and accordingly loading (its near)scenes by matching its position. But it is not smooth. . .

How do I load big scene smoothly? what will be the strategy? Is this right strategy which I am doing or there is any other feasible and easy to use solution available.?

Comment: There are different methods to load scenes. `Application.LoadLevel`, `SceneManager.LoadScene` and `SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync` are those I can think of right now, but there might be more. Which one are you using? There are also different kinds of "not smooth". Is there a freeze? Is there bad FPS for several frames? Is the framerate good, but objects jump around when you load a new scene? Is there a notable "pop-in" of the new content you want to conceal somehow? Please clarify the problem.

Comment: Sector and World Streamer are the most used Unity Asset when talking about streaming big environment just search on asset store

Comment: I don't know about sector but i have check streamer 2 years ago it suddenly popup the loading environment and also it low down the fps when loading a new scene.